# What is the use of Apex Sharing if we are using permission set

Tags: permission-sets, apex-sharing

This is interview question and I could not answer

Comment: Thanks for being upfront about this being an interview question. I've still downvoted it though because you haven't shown that you've made any attempt at researching this first (and it sounds like something that should be easy to research).

Comment: Really sorry for this. I have answered the difference between them.. that is why i said i coul d not answer.

Comment: I’m voting to close this question because it is not a question.

Answer (score 4):

Speaking generally

Permission sets = controls access to SObjects and fields
Sharing = controls access to individual records of an SObject

When I use my preferred search engine, and search for "apex sharing vs permission set", the second link is to [an official help article](https://help.salesforce.com/s/articleView?id=sf.security_data_access.htm&type=5) which corroborates this

> Salesforce data sharing lets you expose specific data sets to individuals and groups of users. Permission sets, permission set groups, and profiles provide object-level and field-level security by controlling access. Record-level sharing settings, user roles, and sharing rules control the individual records that users can view and edit.

Comment: Probably also worth pointing to trailhead for [sharing](https://trailhead.salesforce.com/content/learn/modules/data_security/data_security_records) and [permissions](https://trailhead.salesforce.com/content/learn/modules/data_security/data_security_objects).